# Adding the attribute Required to an input Text

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i have an asp.net mvc4 application in which i have :

```
 <li>
                @Html.Label("Login")
                @Html.TextBox("Login")

            </li>
```

i'd like to add the attribute `Required` to the TextBox `login` like this

```
<input type="Text name="login" Required />
```

how can i do it?

Comment: @Html.TextBox("Login", null, new { required = "required" }) should helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@Html.TextBox(
    "Login", 
    null, 
    new { 
        required = "required" 
    }
)
```

Comment: But this will enter `required = "required"`. He needs only just `required`. Rite?

Answer (score 2):

An alternate way can be to add data annotation in model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Field  cannot be blank")]
```